# IN() function with multiple parameter

Tags: mysql

Sample Data

[image]

When I am set parameter as in following way the not getting properly result.

**Query:**

```
SET @parmClientList ='7,11,14';

Select fkUserID from tbluserclient where MultipleClientID IN(@parmClientList);
```

but when I declare directly as hard coded then I getting proper result.

**Query:**

```
select fkUserID from tbluserclient where MultipleClientID IN(7,11,14);
```

Can some one suggest me how to pass multiple value to IN() function parameter.

Comment: Can you name any programming language where, if you pass it a *single* parameter that happens to contain various characters, including commas, it will decide to instead treat that as multiple separate parameters instead? I'm not familiar with any such language, and SQL isn't such a language.

Comment: You should normalize your data. Putting comma-separated lists in a field is poor design, and it makes queries like this very difficu.t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list in the `IN()` condition has to be a literal list, it won't split a string. Use `FIND_IN_SET()`.

```
SELECT fkUserID FROM tbluserClient
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(CAST(MultipleClientID AS DECIMAL), @parmClientList);
```

Using `CAST(MultipleClientID AS DECIMAL)` performs the same conversion of that column from a comma-separated list to a single number that you get when you test it with `IN(7,11,14)`. In both cases, it just checks whether the first number in the column is in the list.

Comment: SET @parmClientList ='7,11,14';
select fkUserID from tbluserclient where FIND_IN_SET(MultipleClientID,@parmClientList);
select fkUserID from tbluserclient where MultipleClientID IN(7,11,14); both gives me different result, but correct result set gives me second query. Using IN() function

Comment: So can you please give solution, how to pass multiple value to IN() function.

Comment: I just added a sqlfiddle demo showing that my solution works.

Comment: That's the same comment you wrote before, it's not helping.

Comment: Please put sample data and the expected result in the question.

Comment: Please find sample data above.

Comment: That's only getting the correct answer when you use `IN` by accident. When it converts `MultipleClientID` to a number to match it against the `IN` list, it just uses the first number in the comma-separated list, and all the IDs you looked for were the first. It won't work with `IN (10)` because that's the second number in the list.

Comment: Can you post the data in plain text so I can copy it into the fiddle instead of having to retype it?